# Sequalize Conversion

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2}]

{ id: [1,2,3,4] }
```

I'm getting an incentive in the first arrangement yet I need the second configuration of significant worth. How do I change this in a single sequalize inquiry?

Thank you for helping me to illuminate this.

Comment: Sequelize will always return an array of objects, the only solution for that is to do a mapping after you get the query.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping can be done in following way.

```
const result = [{"id":1},{"id":2}]
{
    id: result.map((o)=>{ o.id })
}
```